# "debuggable false" is enough to prevent debugging my App?

Tags: java, android, debugging

I see that many users are using the attribute `debuggable false` in the release build:

```
release {
    debuggable false
    ...
}
```

It is also suggested by the official documentation, so I think it's a security measure or at least a method to avoid reverse engineering and / or app data theft.

But, it's enough to prevent debugging my App?

I already searched with Google and in Stack Overflow but I found only information about that attribute.

For "debugging" I don't mean "reverse engineering" done observing the App behavior, but debug the App by connecting it to another program/software to get information about it, e.g. the Android Studio debugger.

I'm using `Java` with the latest version of Android Studio on a Ubuntu Linux machine.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define "debugging". Generally: no, nothing can ever stop an interested engineer from debugging your app, it can only ever make it more difficult.

Comment: It is more for not packing debug information with the actual code. File names and line numbers.

Comment: @luk2302 for "debugging" I don't mean "reverse engineering" but debug the App by connecting it to another program/software to get information about it.

Comment: @JoopEggen I already setted `minified true` in the release build and removed all `Log` invocations from the source Java code.

Answer (score 2):

The `debuggable` setting in the manifest tells the running system that the app may have a debugger attached.  For Java/Kotlin based apps (e.g. any 3rd party Android app), this causes the system to spin up an internal thread which allows a debugger to attach to the process.  This is in-line with traditional Java app debugging.  In fact, you can attach any JDWP compliant debugger (such as `jdp`) to the process.  Without this setting, the process will not have a debug thread listening on a port so no JDWP debugger can be attached.  This is not the same as attaching `gdb` and having symbols built into an executable image.  Android apps are not your typical executable.

On a typical Linux system, something like gdb could be "attached" to any running process.  Though, the ease of use will vary depending on whether debug symbols were built into the image.  However, on Android the system security will prevent a shell process from attaching to any process using `gdb`, unless it is a development system or one which has been rooted.

Comment: thanks for your reply, why you are talking about `debuggable` set in the manifest? I post the example of that attribute in the gradle file inside the relase setting, maybe these are the same setting? thanks

Comment: Because ultimately that `debuggable` setting in the gradle file is used to generate a setting in the `AndroidManifest.xml` which is included (in a compiled form) in the app's APK.

Comment: There are also other things set in the gradle file which are automatically injected into the manifest file, such as the `applicationId`.  You can find the "merged" manifest which is ultimately bundled into your APK in the `app/build` directory of your tree, such as `app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/<build flavor and variant>/AndroidManifest.xml`.  See this page for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element

Comment: Based on what you say, I can understand that there can always be a way to attach my App process to a "debugger" or similar software. So, can I do something inside the App's Java code in order to discover if the App is debugged or not and, if so, react by terminating my App process?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. When an app is marked `debuggable`, the system creates a thread within the app's process which Java debuggers may connect to and control the process. Without the `debuggable` setting enabled, there will be no JDWP compliant way to connect a debugger to the app.  To use a native level debugger, such as `gdb`, requires a rooted Android device or development system (e.g. custom ROM) and it works by hooking low level signal handlers in the process.